# Re-generating model file with textx

Tags: python, dsl, textx

I'm new with DSL and I'm not sure if it's possible the tasks that I want to do with textx:

1. I already have language description textX (ex: hello.tx)
2. Load an initial model file for this language (ex: example.hello)
3. Edit the currently loaded model.
4. Re-generate a new model file (new_example.hello) with the additions.

Is it possible to do it with textx?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Programmatically changing the model and then persisting back to the textual syntax is not supported at this time in textX.

There is [an issue registered](https://github.com/textX/textX/issues/36) to track this feature request.